# vuex how mutate multiple properties in store like in redux?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, react-redux, vuex

Vuex approach for state mutations is as following:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    fetching: false,
    board: null
  },
  mutations: {
    setFething (state) {
      state.fetching = true
    },
    setCurrentBoard (state, board) {
       state.board = board
       state.fetching = false
    }
  }
})
```

But I’m afraid that it will trigger two changes for `board` and `fetching` independently instead one and my view will be updated double times for each property.
It is only simple example, I’ve more complex properties mutations that will be better to mutate by one mutation. Is it possible in vuex?

I liked redux approach to return state object mutated only once:

```
initialState = { board: null, fetching: false };
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Constants.SET_FETCHING:
      return { ...state, fetching: true };

    case Constants.SET_CURRENT_BOARD:
      return { ...state, ...action.board, fetching: false };
 }
```

Comment: Use Vuex acrions. Create action in which you commit multiple changes at same time.

Comment: The case is that I can’t return new immutable state object at once but I’ve to mutate each property separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, are you looking for something like this?

```js
var store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    id: 1,
    name: 'aaa',
    last: 'bbb'
  },
  mutations: {
    change (state, payload) {
      state = Object.assign(state, payload)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  created () {
    setTimeout(_ => {
      this.$store.commit('change', {
        id: 2,
        last: 'ccc'
      })
    }, 2000)
    setTimeout(_ => {
      this.$store.commit('change', {
        name: 'ddd'
      })
    }, 4000)
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  {{ $store.state.id }}
  <br>
  {{ $store.state.name }}
  <br>
  {{ $store.state.last }}
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex"></script>
```